# is_shop doesn't work for woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to hide woocommerce breadcrum in only woocommerce archive page. And i want to display it in single product. So i write this code in functions.php:

```
if(is_shop()) {
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20);
}
```

But it not hiding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_shop()` is returning false because the WordPress query isn't set up yet when `functions.php` is run. If you attach it to a hook, like `wp_loaded`, it should work.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'remove_main_content' );
function remove_main_content() {
  if( is_shop() ) {
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20 );
  }
}
```